# How to set environment variables with bosh?

Tags: bosh-deployer

Is there a convention or place in the deploy manifest to specify environment variables for machines? Or would I have to write a shell script to do this? If I have to do that, do I have to set them in a pre-job hook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating a release, the convention is to set and export only those environment variables that your particular job/process needs and to do so in the job's control script.

For example, the bosh release exports several environment variables like `GEM_HOME` and `http_proxy` in the control/shell script which starts the director process ([ref](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/bosh/blob/93a2522b3a6a58cc3d24f6ea10a9dba0a9a421bb/release/jobs/director/templates/director_ctl.erb#L21-L43)). The `GEM_HOME` statically points to its own package directory, and the `http_proxy` is conditionally set based on operator-configured properties from the deployment manifest.

The [`pre-start`](https://bosh.io/docs/pre-start.html) hook is executed in its own process, so any environment variables that your `pre-start` script tries to export will not be propagated to other shell scripts that are later executed by bosh or monit.